# Update glm using match.call()

Tags: r, regression, call, glm

Lets say I have the following model:

```
mod1 <- glm(cyl ~ mpg + disp, data = mtcars)
```

Then I would like to modify some elements in the glm call. For example a new formula and new data:

```
fm_new <- formula(cyl ~ mpg + disp + offset(log(gear)))
df_new <- mtcars
```

And combine the new elements to a list:

```
lst1 <- list(fm = fm_new, df = df_new, mod_call = mod1$call)
```

Then in the last step I would like to pass this list to `glm2()` to refit the glm:

```
glm2 <- function(x){
  fm <- x$fm
  df <- x$df
  glm(fm, data = df)
}
```

This returns the refitted glm:

```
glm2(lst1)  

# Call:  glm(formula = fm, data = df)
#
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          mpg         disp  
#     4.44751     -0.09326      0.01009  
#
# Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  29 Residual
# Null Deviance:        111.5 
# Residual Deviance: 16.34  AIC: 77.3
```

However, the above only works if I define the arguments in the glm call in `glm2()` explicitly, what i would like to achieve is that `glm()` in `glm2()` uses exactly the same elements in the call as `mod1`. So for example:

```
mod2 <- glm(cyl ~ mpg + disp, family = "poisson", weights = am, data = mtcars)
```

Then add all new elements to a list:

```
lst2 <- list(fm = fm_new, df = df_new, mod_call = mod2$call)
```

Here `glm2()` should also use the Poisson GLM and weights from `mod2`. How can I modify `glm2()` such that it also contains the family and weights used in `mod2` (or other arguments passed to `mod2`)? I am aware of `match.call()` but don't exactly get how that works here.

The following is what I would like to achieve:

```
glm2(lst2)

# Call:  glm(formula = fm, family = "poisson", data = df, weights = am)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          mpg         disp  
#    0.374368    -0.017450     0.001163  
#
# Degrees of Freedom: 12 Total (i.e. Null);  10 Residual
# Null Deviance:        4.037 
# Residual Deviance: 1.256  AIC: 52.23
```

Comment: Thanks. Good answer. I modified `df_new` to `quote(df_new)`.

Comment: Why not just use the [`update`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/update.html) function? All you need is `mod2 <- update(mod1, formula = fm_new, data = df_new)`.